# Yii2: Как создать в таблице поле created_at?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2, datetime

Создаю таблицу (MYSQL) через миграцию. Сейчас это выглядит так:

```
$this->createTable('{{%values}}', [
            'id' => $this->primaryKey(),
            'value' => $this->integer()->notNull(),
        ]);
```

Хочу добавить сюда поле, содержащее в себе дату и время создания этого поля. На чистом SQL описание этого поля при создании таблицы было бы таким:

```
`название_поля` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Не совсем понимаю, как добавить это в свой код. Подскажите, пожалуйста :)

Comment: [Class yii\db\DefaultValueConstraint](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-defaultvalueconstraint)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего так:

```
'created_at' => $this->dateTime()->defaultExpression('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'),
```